# Activiti SubProcess Signal

Tags: workflow, activiti

I have activiti process, that does not seem to work the way I expect it to.

Process is pretty straightforward:

1. Once process is started, it starts subprocess.
2. Subprocess has parallel gateway, that branches to signal catching event and user tasks.
3. Once singal is caught, subprocess throws error (end error event).
4. While signal is not caught, user can complete tasks.
5. Then main process catches that error and ends process.

**My problem:** I start 4 such processes, that use 1 singal. When this signal is sent, all 4 of them should be ended. But they are not. It seems they are ended in random order? Somtimes 1 or 2 are ended, but never all of them...I get no errors/exceptions and have no idea what is wrong...
It would seem that some processes just wont catch the signal that is sent to them. Why could that be so?

Process schema:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added logging to your "check caught signal conditions" to determine if all signals actually trigger this step?
Also, you can query signal subscriptions to determine if you have as many as you expect:

List executions = runtimeService.createExecutionQuery()
   .signalEventSubscriptionName("alert")
   .list();

I expect either your check logic is not processing correctly or you dont have a "token" waiting at the signal.

Greg

Comment: You were right, signals were not being caught (immediately, as I thought they should), but after some time they were. Problem was fixed.

Comment: Yup, one thing people dont realize is that the Job scheduler architecture doesnt guarantee immediate response, all jobs will ultimately be processed but it could take some time depending on the load. Glad you sorted it out (would appreciate an up vote :-) )

Answer (score 0):

I have created simple jUnit test based on the already existing signal boundary event tests in flowable project (should behave in the same way as activiti)

```
 @Deployment(resources = "org/activiti/engine/test/bpmn/event/signal/SignalEventTest.testSignalBoundaryOnSubProcess.bpmn20.xml")
public void testMultipleCatchEventsOnSubProcess() {
ProcessInstance processInstance1 = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("signalEventOnSubprocess");
ProcessInstance processInstance2 = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("signalEventOnSubprocess");
ProcessInstance processInstance3 = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("signalEventOnSubprocess");

assertThat("There must be three subscriptions to the signal.", createEventSubscriptionQuery().count(), is(3L));

runtimeService.signalEventReceived("stopSignal");

assertProcessEnded(processInstance1.getProcessInstanceId());
assertProcessEnded(processInstance2.getProcessInstanceId());
assertProcessEnded(processInstance3.getProcessInstanceId());
}
```

The test passes. Could you create failing jUnit test to reproduce the issue (with the dependencies)?

Martin

Comment: Thanks for the junit test, but I fixed the problem (or rather there was not a problem as I understood it).